# ImageSource in a class library won't show

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My application links to a class library (.dll). In the class library project, three images were put into Resources.resx. One image needs to be chosen at run time and shown on a button. After googling around, I choose to use a converter to help the binding in xaml:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Side), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class SideToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Side side = (Side)value;
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                return ToWpfBitmap(Properties.Resources.LeftArmOnCart);
            case Side.Right:
                return ToWpfBitmap(Properties.Resources.RightArmOnCart);
            case Side.Both:
                return ToWpfBitmap(Properties.Resources.RightArmOnCart);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Current configuration is invalid");
        }
    }

    private static BitmapSource ToWpfBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            stream.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
            result.BeginInit();
            // According to MSDN, "The default OnDemand cache option retains access to the stream until the image is needed."
            // Force the bitmap to load right now so we can dispose the stream.
            result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            result.StreamSource = stream;
            result.EndInit();
            result.Freeze();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The xaml code looks like

```
<Image Source="{Binding Side, Converter={StaticResource SideToImageConverter}}" .../>
```

Unfortunately, the image won't show silently without throwing any exception. Debug into the converter code, the bitmap argument in ToWpfBitmap() looks fine (the Width/Height values were correct).

BTW, as another trial, the following code works fine.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Side), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class SideToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Side side = (Side)value;
        switch (side)
        {
            case Side.Left:
                return LoadBitmap("LeftArmOnCart.png");
            case Side.Right:
                return LoadBitmap("RightArmOnCart.png");
            case Side.Both:
                return LoadBitmap("RightArmOnCart.png");
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Current configuration is invalid");
        }
    }

    private static BitmapSource LoadBitmap(string name)
    {
        BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
        result.BeginInit();
        string uri = "c:/.../Resources/Images/" + name;
        result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        result.UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute);
        result.EndInit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, absolute path is not desired. So, do I miss anything?

I understand that it is feasible to use relative path by releasing the three image files. But, is it possible NOT to release the three files but just the class library dll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I think you could read up on to help you with your problem.  I would start with [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can understand how to use a URI to check a specific library's location.  Since these images are in another assembly's resource file, read the "Referenced Resource Assembly File" in the link.

I think the other thing worth mentioning is the difference between the two methods is one you provide a `UriSource` to (bottom) and one you don't (top).  Looking at [`Image.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx), when used in XAML it expects a `imageUri`.  With that hint, we can say it is definitely something to do with URIs probably.

In fact, your images are already saved as a stream inside of the libraries that they exist in, so we don't need to do anything with creating a new bitmap or whatever you're doing, instead we can simply provide a valid pack URI and return a string.

I'm thinking something like this should work, provided the name of the library the images are in is `YourApp.Models`, in sub folder `Resources\Images\`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    Side side = (Side)value;
    switch (side)
    {
        case Side.Left:
            return "pack://application:,,,/YourApp.Models;component/Resources/Images/LeftArmOnCart.png";
        case Side.Right:
        case Side.Both:
            return "pack://application:,,,/YourApp.Models;component/Resources/Images/RightArmOnCart.png";
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Current configuration is invalid");
    }
}
```

**Note:** Path names are sensitive to forward/back slash, assembly names, component.  Be sure everything is correctly formatted.

This is considered an absolute URI.  A relative URI would be just `"/Resources/Images/LeftArmOnCart.png"` which would only work if that file path existed within the assembly that called it--meaning it wouldn't work for you since you're calling from another assembly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While `pack:` URIs can be used to access files compiled as `Resource` or `Content`, they cannot be used to access resources compiled as an `Embedded Resource` (`.resx`).

Comment: True.  I would probably add them to the solution and set their build action to Resource if the application won't be localized and you're images are branding bitmaps that you don't want to be changed.

Comment: Great. This solution works. Looks like you are right that the binding is expecting a valid UriSource.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an `InteropBitmap` class that can be used to convert a GDI bitmap to a WPF `ImageSource`, though I find it doesn't handle alpha channels very well.  This is the mechanism I use:

```
public static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSourceFromGdiBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    if (bitmap == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
        rect,
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    try
    {
        var size = (rect.Width * rect.Height) * 4;

        return BitmapSource.Create(
            bitmap.Width,
            bitmap.Height,
            bitmap.HorizontalResolution,
            bitmap.VerticalResolution,
            PixelFormats.Bgra32,
            null,
            bitmapData.Scan0,
            size,
            bitmapData.Stride);
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation assumes 32bpp ARGB pixel format.  That should be fine if you're using PNG images.  Otherwise, you'll need to add a conversion step.

Comment: Tried, but still won't show silently without throwing any exceptions. Feel like this is essentially similar to the function *ToWpfBitmap()* that I was using. Isn't it?

Comment: Not quite the same--mine copies the already-decoded bitmap data, while yours encodes back to PNG format, then decodes again.  Fewer stages for something to go wrong.  What is the PixelFormat of the Bitmap loaded from the library resources?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The PxielFormat is seen in debugger to be *Format32bppArgb*.